# iOS10 today extension doesn't work in expanded mode

Tags: ios

I have today extension in my app, using expanded mode with the code:

```
self.extensionContext.widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode = NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded;
```

and

```
- (void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize {
if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeExpanded) {
    self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(0.0, 215.0);
}
else if (activeDisplayMode == NCWidgetDisplayModeCompact) {
    self.preferredContentSize = maxSize;
}}
```

it works OK in new apps but it doesn't work in my existing apps made in previous versions of xcode. the widget is always in compact mode with no "show more/less" button.
Any idea why?
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40482917/how-to-create-widgets-showing-on-home-screen-in-ios-10/40484516#40484516

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40653242/today-widget-extension-height-ios10

Answer (score -1):

widgetLargestAvailableDisplayMode
Link: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsextensioncontext/1649133-widgetlargestavailabledisplaymod

(void)widgetActiveDisplayModeDidChange:(NCWidgetDisplayMode)activeDisplayMode withMaximumSize:(CGSize)maxSize This has been introduced from iOS 10 onwards.
Link : https://developer.apple.com/reference/notificationcenter/ncwidgetproviding/1649132-widgetactivedisplaymodedidchange?language=objc

Thats the reason why you are not getting same buttons in iOS 8/9.

Same behavior could be replicated in iOS 8/9 by adding showMore button at bottom of widget , which you could see in other widgets as well.